# Jquery ajax not triggering when hitting 'warning'

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I have an ajax call connected to a search that is calling an api that is spitting back jsonp results. This seems to be working fantastically except when they type something that is not there.

I get back a jsonp file in the console that is giving me a 'warning'

```
jQuery3600877660906184312_1652368192872({
    "status": "warning",
    "messages": {
        "generalMessages": [{
            "messageID": "1027",
            "messageCriticality": "warning",
            "messageText": "You provided an invalid field name."
        }, {
            "messageID": "1027",
            "messageCriticality": "warning",
            "messageText": "You provided an invalid field name."
        }, {
            "messageID": "1027",
            "messageCriticality": "warning",
            "messageText": "You provided an invalid field name."
        }],
        "recordMessages": []
    },
    "foundRows": 0,
    "data": []
})
```

I have tried to account for this in my ajax call by adding a "fail" and a "warning" just hoping to catch it so I can handle it. Nothing seems to want to catch this though. Any ideas?

```
var encoded = $.toJSON(search)
    $('#animalList').empty();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url' + encoded,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
               // do stuff
        },
        warning: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('warning');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log('error');
        }
    });
```

Comment: The ajax *request* and *response* was a success, ie a 200 http code, ie it did not "fail" to get *some* data back.   What that data contains/means is irrelevant to the request.  A request was made and some data was returned, so it goes in `success:`.   There's no (conceivable) way that jquery would know to check your data for a "random" property called "status".

Comment: `success: function (data) { if (data.success == "warning") return console.error("warning"); ...`

Comment: @freedomn-m It's not getting into the success function at all though, why it has me confused. I did give that a try, putting the if in the success, but it just skips over everything and adds that response file to the script folder. No data is actually coming back, just that error message